# Unknown type of equation in dsolve

Tags: python, sympy, ode

I need to solve this system related to achemical reactor. I used sympy and have not been able to solve the error in any way

My code is here:

```py
from sympy import symbols, Function, dsolve, Eq, Derivative, sin, cos

Pf, Po, Pm, Pc, Ph, Pn = symbols('Pf Po Pm Pc Ph Pn', cls=Function)

#Pf-furfural pressure; Po-oxygen pressure; Pm-maleic anhydride pressure; Pco-carbon dioxide pressure; Ph-steam pressure; Pn-nitrogen pressure*

W, k1, k2, k3, n, m, l, R, T, vt, Pt = symbols('W k1 k2 k3 n m l R T vt Pt')

#W-catalyst mass; k1-kinetic constant first reaction; k2-kinetic constant second reaction; k3-kinetic constant third reaction; n, m y l, reaction orders for oxygen in the first, second and third reaction, respectively; R- universal gas constant, T-temperature, vt-catalyst volume*

A = R*T/vt

Pt = Pf(W)+Pf(W)+Pm(W)+Pc(W)+Ph(W)+Pn(W)

eq=((Eq(Derivative(Pf(W), W), (-A*k1*Pf(W)*(Po(W)**n)-A*k2*Pf(W)*(Po(W)**m)))),
    (Eq(Derivative(Po(W), W), (-A*k1*Pf(W)*(Po(W)**n)-A*k2*Pf(W)*(Po(W)**m)-A*k3*Pm(W)*(Po(W)**l)))),
    (Eq(Derivative(Pm(W), W), (A*k1*Pf(W)*(Po(W)**n)-A*k3*Pm(W)*(Po(W)**l)))),
    (Eq(Derivative(Pc(W), W), (A*k1*Pf(W)*(Po(W)**n)+5*A*k2*Pf(W)*(Po(W)**m)+4*A*k3*Pm(W)*(Po(W)**l)))),
    (Eq(Derivative(Ph(W), W), (A*k1*Pf(W)*(Po(W)**n)+2*A*k2*Pf(W)*(Po(W)**m)+A*k3*Pm(W)*(Po(W)**l)))),
    (Eq(Derivative(Pn(W), W), (0))))

dsolve(eq, [Pf(W), Po(W), Pm(W), Pc(W), Ph(W), Pn(W)], hint="all")
```

After I run the code, the following error appears

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-42dc4d2e7b25> in <module>
----> 1 dsolve(eq)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\ode.py in dsolve(eq, func, hint, simplify, ics, xi, eta, x0, n, **kwargs)
    607             "number of functions being equal to number of equations")
    608         if match['type_of_equation'] is None:
--> 609             raise NotImplementedError
    610         else:
    611             if match['is_linear'] == True:

NotImplementedError:
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to stackoverflow. Your post looks like it's all source code and output / error message, but it's not all formatted as code. Can you please [edit] your question and format it? Use the `{}` button for code. Also, trim the title, and include the explanation in the question itself. See also [ask].

Answer (score 1):

The `sympy` functions for symbolic differential equation solving are experimental and not very complete, so you should take the error message at face value, your system does not fall into any category that has a solver method.

Moreover, general differential equations and more so systems of DE do not possess a symbolic solution, the set that does is very "thin", slight changes to a symbolically solvable equation will turn it unsolvable. This means that even a more complete library of symbolic solver methods like for instance the one of Mathematica can not find a symbolic solution.

So you need to work out what you really want (plot of the solution, fitting of parameters, etc.) and then find a suitable numerical method.

Comment: I just need to adjust parameters, so I will work on that